# Layout has changed. How to undo it?

Tags: support

Is it possible to use the old layout of TGO? Everything is bright as the sun, I think I need some sunglasses here (at night!).

Comment: In a word, *no* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't realised there had been a change, but as Liam stated, with every styling change across the Stack Exchange network, there are complaints from many people - but it doesn't change the outcome:

- Someone will always hate the new layout
- Someone will always love it

Comment: *"...but it doesn't change the outcome."*  ← That's not true. The CSS refactoring was only recently released, so problems inevitably get by the designers and they are addressed. Sometimes visual anomalies are highly device-specific, so I can't guarantee every report can or will be accommodated... but they ***are*** heard, and the users' feedback here drives more features and changes than anything we come up with!

Comment: Important to  note that Rory has been around for _quite_ a long time on _quite_ a few sites, and while these sorts of things have (yes) _always_ been heard, we didn't always communicate that very well through response. That _is_ getting quite a bit better, as Robert points out.

Comment: Ah - I realise my post could have come across quite negatively. It was more a tongue in cheek dig at the fact that no matter what the layout, someone will hate it and others will love it.

Comment: @Rory I am sure you are right on that. And I know it for myself, sometimes it just *needs* some time to get used to something new. Still that isn't answering my question, if it is possible to change it locally. I guess (well I am pretty sure) this isn't possible, like Liam said.

Comment: Oh, it is always possible to change it locally through CSS tweaks. Meta.se has many posts on this topic.